# HttpClientException : Request Failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy, http-proxy

Whenever I run my application, I'm getting the **connection request failure exception**. The application tries to hit the URL and end up with connection failure.

I have tried the same on `Postman`. It is giving me `200: OK`.

I have the proxy and port as well. How to use it in our spring boot application. Whenever the application runs it should take the respective proxy and port.
I'm attaching here the logs:

```
creating event for user 0852 for campaign source TEST at stage INITIAL_LANDING
creating event for user 0852 for campaign source TEST at stage CLICK_DEMO
2019-07-19 15:15:39.680  INFO 49560 --- [nio-9898-exec-8] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {s}->https://pi-collector-dev.tr-corporate-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:443: Connection reset
2019-07-19 15:15:39.683  INFO 49560 --- [nio-9898-exec-8] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Retrying connect to {s}->https://pi-collector-dev.tr-corporate-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:443
2019-07-19 15:15:49.302  INFO 49560 --- [nio-9898-exec-8] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {s}->https://pi-collector-dev.tr-corporate-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:443: Connection reset
2019-07-19 15:15:49.304  INFO 49560 --- [nio-9898-exec-8] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Retrying connect to {s}->https://pi-collector-dev.tr-corporate-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:443
2019-07-19 15:15:58.904  INFO 49560 --- [nio-9898-exec-8] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {s}->https://pi-collector-dev.tr-corporate-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:443: Connection reset
2019-07-19 15:15:58.906  INFO 49560 --- [nio-9898-exec-8] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Retrying connect to {s}->https://pi-collector-dev.tr-corporate-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:443
2019-07-19 15:16:08.665 ERROR 49560 --- [nio-9898-exec-8] c.t.providers.persistent.InMemoryQueue   : Failed to push events to destination.
```

Comment: can you share the piece of your code that causes your error?

Comment: In config.properties, I have the URL and TOKEN. That I'm making use of it in my controller class. 
I do have https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort number. May be I'm thinking these I have to use it in application.properties so that the URL should pick this up.

In Postman I'm getting 200:OK -> Success.

Comment: @JWo Anything else you want from my side?